# Honda Odyssey 16 inch rims

Tags: honda, tires, odyssey

I have a 2015 Honda Odyssey which has 17 inch rims and tires on it,  can I put on 16 inch rims and tires on it?

Comment: We need to know what year your vehicle is and what options it has in order to answer this question.

Comment: Which engine do you have? 2.4L inline-4 or 3.5L V6?

Comment: I have a V6 /3.5 L

Answer (score 1):

According to Canadian Tire's wheel selector (in their app), your choices range from 17 to 20 inches, regardless of submodel. So no, 16 inches isn't an option.